# JQuery sortable tr

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have html table like below, i want "Group 1" items to be sorted only between "Group 1" items.

I'm using jQuery.sortable.

Since all are table rows(tr), i'm not able to restrict one group item being sorted with another group item.

```html
<table border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Group 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A4</td>
      <td>B4</td>
      <td>C4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A5</td>
      <td>B5</td>
      <td>C5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A6</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class like `class="group1"` to `tr`s and use `connectWith: ".group1"` like below:

```
$(".group1").sortable({
 connectWith: ".group1"
});
```

[**Online demo (fiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/943Lmpdd/)

Comment: How to apply selector for connectWith property.
selector something like jQuery("tr[groupid=1]")